# Not able to login in facebook with facebook sdk 3.0 loginbutton button using other users, though it is working with developers login credentials

Tags: android

As a developer , if i am supplying my username and password to login into facebook, it is working fine. but if other facebook user if trying to login into facebook using my app, it is not working. I am using Facebook SDK 3.0 LoginButton for logging in and logging out of facebook. Is there any setting change that I have to make on developers.facebook.com/app? I have tried that but did not found any such settings. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your facebook's dev account check that your app is set to sandbox mode, so only developer accounts could get access token from app's ID, once you disable sandbox mode, your app will go live and you can log in with any facebook id.